# WebRTC iOS Getting the Code "gclient sync" take long time

Tags: ios, macos, webrtc

I get the WebRTC iOS code like this method 
https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/

but it's take long time and still print out

```
[0:02:40] Still working on:
[0:02:40]   src
```

How long will it take? I run it about 3 hours.
Is there another way to get WebRTC Code for iOS?

Comment: It needs to download a lot of files, it really depends on your internet connection. One thing that might help (since compiling it is a whole other headache your gonna have to deal with after this) is using cocoapods if you don't need to edit the source. [These build scripts make it very easy to quickly fetch and build a certain revision](https://github.com/pristineio/webrtc-build-scripts#ios-armv7-arm64-i386-and-mac-x86_64----guide-here), how to use webrtc with cocoapods is described directly under it.

Answer (score 0):

It takes like 10 minutes to download. Be patience! I think this is the best way to get the official code of Webrtc